# Unexpected token default in Chrome with ({}).default

Tags: javascript

I receive error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token default"
while getting or setting attribute "default" on any object in Chrome (+Opera).

```
({}).default
```

Can someone explain why this happens ?

**upd:** everybody, plz, becareful it doesn't make sense for FF so while testing you can miss this bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`default` is a keyword in JavaScript (for the `switch` statement).

Using reserved words in dot property accessors is allowed in ECMAScript Fifth Edition (specifically: the syntax for the dot property accessor is `MemberExpression . IdentifierName` [section 12.2.1], and `IdentifierName`, unlike `Identifier`, may be a `ReservedWord` [section 7.6]), but not in ECMAScript Third Edition (where it's `MemberExpression . Identifier`). Third Edition is currently the baseline all browsers support.

For safety use `[]` property access:

```
({})['default']= ...;
```

or avoid using keywords as property names.