# Filling out an interactive form

Tags: javascript

I want to fill out an invitation.

Under recipient name I type in the recipient name and then reload the page but nothing happens.  The text I put there still remains along with the organization name, event date, url, and host name.

Such as under recipient name I put Gwendalyn Bears and Organization Name I put Tech Industries.  Then when I reload the page those names are still there.

Below is my javascript code.  It is only two lines but that's all I got at the moment.

```
function resetForm() {
  document.getElementById("recipientName").value = default;
}
```

My html document so you will know what I am doing. Just so you know I am having to put Javascript into the code. Variables in a form is what it is called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
<title>Invitation Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
</head>

<body>
<header>
<div class="top">
    <a class="logo" href="index.html">CapellaVolunteers<span class="dotcom">.org</span></a>
</div>
<nav>
    <ul class="topnav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="invitation.html" class="active">Invitation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="registration.html">Registration</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</nav>
</header>
<section id="pageForm">
<form action="#">
    <label for="recipientName">Recipient name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="recipientName" placeholder="Enter your  Recipient Name" />

    <label for="organizationName">Organization name:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="organizationName" placeholder="Enter your Organization Name" />

    <label for="eventDate">Event Date:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="eventDate" placeholder="Enter your Event Date" />

    <label for="websiteURL">URL:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="websiteURL" placeholder="Enter your Website URL" />

    <label for="hostName">Host name:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="hostName" placeholder="Host Name" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</section>


<article id="placeholderContent">
Hello <span id="recipientName">recipientName</span>!
<br/>
<br/> You have been invited to volunteer for an event held by <span id="organizationName">organizationName</span> on <span id="eventDate">eventDate</span>. Please come to the following website: <span id="websiteURL">websiteURL</span> to sign up as a volunteer.
<br/>
<br/> Thanks!
<br/>
<br/>
<span id="hostName">hostName</span>
</article>
<footer>This events site is for IT3215 tasks.
</footer>
<script src="invite.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? Could be that it's just de browser behaviour (auto fill) or something like that. Normally the form is empty when you reload the page without you having to do that with javascript.

Comment: use this: document.getElementById("recipientName").value = 'default'; or to empty it document.getElementById("recipientName").value = '';

Comment: Firefox But I'm actually writing the code for a project

Comment: Should I do it like this: document.getElementById("recipientName").value = placeholder;

Comment: If you write something in the input field here https://jsfiddle.net/jf3tnbrr/ then click on run or reload then it's empty isn't it?

Comment: no it just has whatever i put in there when I click reload.

Comment: What happens in a different browser? See, I'm just trying to avoid you writing code for something you do not need to write code. Cause the next step you will figure out that people fill out your form, submit to server there you find that one value is wrong, so send back the form with an error message and then you don't want to set all fields back to default. I would leave the page and never come back. I hate it if I have to fill out a form twice. The default behaviour of every browser is the fields are empty on reload!

Comment: Here let me just show you exactly what I need to do. add functionality to an interactive form that generates an invitation to volunteers for an event. The file will have the following invitation message placeholder and a form below it. You will add JavaScript to the form that will allow a user to dynamically fill out the invitation.
    Hello __recipientName_____!
    You have been invited to volunteer for an event held by __organizationName_____ on ___eventDate_____. Please come to the following Web site: <insert your Web site URL> to sign up as a volunteer.
    Thanks!
    __hostName__

Comment: default is a reserved token in Javascript. use a different variable to achieve this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942364/unexpected-token-default-in-chrome-with-default

Comment: Anyone have any ideas as to how I could do this

Comment: @Jdawg32 How about using placeholders instead. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXaWgz?editors=1010